# Borrar archivos y directorios de un directorio excepto un archivo concreto con php

Tags: php

Necesito ejecutar un cron semanal para borrar los archivos y directorios que genera la cache de prestashop excepto uno, el index.php

Lo he intentado con shell_exec() pero mi servidor tiene desactivada esa función por motivos de seguridad.

Agradezco mucho vuestra ayuda!

un saludo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque sin código, es difícil ayudarte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875/)

Comment: Gracias fedorqui todo un detalle por tu parte y muy útil para usuarios nuevos como yo.

Tu voto negativo me importa 0,00000 ;-)

Comment: Gracias gbanchi! Soy nuevo aquí y ando algo perdido tu comentario si me ha servido de ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Puede recorrer los archivos de una carpeta y validar que no borre el index este es el codigo para recorrerlo y eliminar los archivos

```
$files = glob('my_folder/*'); //obtenemos todos los nombres de los ficheros
foreach($files as $file){
if(is_file($file))
unlink($file); //elimino el fichero
}
```